# How do I get my aliases to have correct completion?

Tags: git, alias, fish

## Aliases that don't tab complete

I have a bunch of aliases like `j` for `jobs` ([here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/dotfiles/blob/eb7e023f4a987d2b99b405bcc254bcf8c3d6ac7e/fish/functions/j.fish)), and "alias commands" like `gs` for `git status` ([here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/dotfiles/blob/eb7e023f4a987d2b99b405bcc254bcf8c3d6ac7e/bin/gs)).

I want them to have the tab completion of the thing they are aliasing. So `j -<TAB>` would complete like `jobs -<TAB>` and recommend --command, --pid, and so on.

---

### Idea1: Extract the definition from the aliased command:

If there's nothing built in to tell it to treat `j` as `jobs`, then perhaps there is a way to do it dynamically? Based on [this comment](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1217#issuecomment-31441757)and [the docs](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/index.html#completion-own), it seems like I should be able to do something like the following:

```
complete --command j (complete --definitions-for jobs)
```

For some made-up flag "--definitions-for", which just outputs whatever flags were put in to get the current definition (I found a function [`complete_print`](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/complete.cpp#L2044) that's pretty close to what I want)

### Idea2: Swap out the commandline:

While this might be possible for j->jobs, I started looking around and found [git status completions](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/706286c28956e51873bfe6b673bea5be01ee7839/share/completions/git.fish#L327-334). It looks like it might be difficult (unless I can expand it before the `-n` condition is checked).

Well, there is a `--do-complete` flag, which says "Print all completions for the specified commandline" Perhaps something along these lines:

```
complete -c gs --do-complete "git status -"
```

I can't actually figure out how to use --do-complete to do anything, though :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported directly yet, but it's highly desired. See [issue 393](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/393) in fish's bug tracker.

The best solution known so far is from [maxfl's comment](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/393#issuecomment-12695100):

```
function make_completion --argument alias command
    complete -c $alias -xa "(
        set -l cmd (commandline -pc | sed -e 's/^ *\S\+ *//' );
        complete -C\"$command \$cmd\";
    )"
end
```

Then you can run `make_completion j jobs` to alias j to jobs. Eventually this will be something you can set directly.

Comment: Wow, even worked with `make_completion gs "git status"` Thank you! I see what my issue was now, I had a space between "--do-complete" and its args!